# No puedo importar datos de excel a mysql

Tags: mysql, excel

Tengo el problema que necesito importar datos de excel a mysql, sin embargo no puedo ni con codigo y mediante el boton que hay en mysql, tengo tambien la aplicacion heidi y tampoco me permite me manda errores, quiero me revisen que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿Cuál botón en mysql?

Comment: en heidi existe un boton de importar csv y el mysql al abrir la tabla con boton derecho aparece una opcion que dice tabla data import wizard

Answer (score 1):

Quizás la columna `indicador_id` en tu tabla es autoincrementable. Si es así, la columna que corresponde a ese campo debes dejarla vacía, es decir, la columna `A` de tu archivo *CSV*.

Comment: Creo que es importante señalar la versión de excel y el sistema operativo. Cuando trabajo excel 2010 en macOS lo tengo que exportar en Valores Separados por comas de Windows (.csv) y no a Valores separados por comas de MS-DOS (.csv) ya que con este último obtengo errores y no carga bien la información.

Answer (score 0):

Con **HeidiSQL**, tienes la opción de **importar CSV**, asi que lo primero que debes hacer es guardar tu fichero **Excel**, en formato CSV separado con comas.

Esto, ya es recomendación personal, edita el CSV, en el notepad, **guárdalo en formato compatible con UTF8**.

Luego en el **HeidiSQL**, dentro de herramientas, usa la opción Importar fichero CSV...

Selecciona las opciones que mejor se adapten a tu fichero y debería cargarse sin problemas.

Lo único a tener en cuenta es que las columnas del CSV, deben corresponder con el mismo orden de base de datos, sino te dará problemas

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda, ya hice lo de la compatibilidad UTF8, efectivamente con heidi intento importarlo con el botón, sin embargo me marca el mismo error: Error de SQL (1366): Incorrect  integer value: "for column 'indicador_id' at arrow 1

Comment: Pon el diseño de la base datos y lo que intentas subir en el csv

Comment: Esta es la consulta que tengo para importar los datos:
load data infile "C:\Users\Teresa\Desktop\respaldo tere\proyecto\prueba.csv" into table indicador;
fields terminated by ',';
lines terminated by '\';

Lo que sigue es lo que quiero subir en csv
Indicador_Id,Acciones,Ctes_pontenciales,Incidentes,Productividad,Prod_empleado,Propuestas,Retencion,Rotacion,Satisfaccion,Similitud,Solicitudes,Hacer solucio_ID
,estable,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,,49,
Y me da un error code 1290

Comment: Hola Teresa, intenta agregar a la pregunta la definición de la tabla,  y que se pueda leer tanto la fila de títulos, como la de los datos. De todas formas prueba en el fichero my.ini, a deshabilitar la opción `secure-file-priv`